# Issue when implementing multiple cell inputs in Angular2

Tags: forms, angular, input

I have a table where each td has an input (like a spreadsheet).

My html template the code as follows:

```
<tr *ngFor="let project of projects" (click)="onSelect(project)">
    <th class="panel fixed">{{project.id}}</th>
    <th class="panel fixed">{{project.name}}</th>

    <td *ngFor="let load of projectLoads[project.code]; let d=index" class="cell panel scrolling">
        <input class="load"  [(ngModel)]="projectLoads[project.code][d]" title="{{project.code+' . '+d}}" />
    </td>
…
```

When I fill one cell in with a number, for example 1, the number is repeated in the next cell.

How it comes?

(Note that there is no ngForm in my current code.)

Comment: Try to add name attribute in your input like this: `name="load_{{d}}"`

Comment: Makes no differences @dev_in_progress